# How to properly use instances in this example?

Tags: c#, class, instances

I have multiple classes and I want to use the functions in other classes. But I'm facing a problem and you might know how to solve it.

Class 1 Inicio:

```
Master master = new Master(ip1.Text);
master.Show();

Master slave = new Master(ip2.Text);
slave.Show();

Arena arena = new Arena();
arena.Show();
```

Class 2 Master:

```
Arena arena = new Arena();

public Master(string ip) //Inicio
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _droneClient = new DroneClient("192.168.1." + ip);
    ip_drone = "192.168.1." + ip; 
    Point p2 = arena.posicao_desej();
    posicao_desejada = p2;

    public string ip_dron()
    {
         return ip_drone;
    }
```

Class 3 Arena:

```
Master master = new Master(""); //What do I insert here? I dont want to iniciate it again

string ip = master.ip_dron();
ip_drone = ip;
```

The problem is in `Master master = new Master("");` If I remove it everything works but I cant use anything from that class. If I use like this the problem will crash once the forms Master and Arena are open. How can I instantiate the instance correctly?

ERROR:

> Make sure you do not an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

**EDIT:
My problem is that since class Inicio will open two different instances from Master, it will use two different ips. When I run the two instances, ip will be ip1.text and then ip2.text. But since they open at the same time return ip_drone will only return the last value ( in this case ip2.text)**

```
   public Master(string ip) //Inicio
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _droneClient = new DroneClient("192.168.1." + ip);
        ip_drone = "192.168.1." + ip;  
    }

   public string ip_dron()
    {
        return ip_drone;
    }
```

Comment: you're creating an infinite loop because Arena creates a new Master (`Master master = new Master("");`). When that's called, it creates a new Arena (`Arena arena = new Arena();`)...which then creates a new Master, which creates a new Arena..and so on, forever and ever. You need to sort out the logic of what code is supposed to initiate what.

Comment: Arena should take an instance of Master: `Arena arena = new Arena(master)`

Comment: A master and slave code are different.  You can't have two connections with the same 3 parameters 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port number.  So the server listens at IP.Any to avoid conflicts.  The root cause of you issue is an exception is occurring and has nothing to do with the instance of the class.

Comment: I dont want to create new instances in Master and Arena. I just want to use the functions from those classes.

Comment: @TiagoSilva then pass the specific instances you want to use into the classes you want to use them in.

Comment: @jdweng that's nonsense. The code is clearly reporting an infinite loop because of the creation of the classes inifinitely. You don't get that error from a networking problem. And anyway it's not using the same IP twice - the two instances to Master in the Inicio get different variables passed to them, which then influence the IP address used. Nowhere does that code distinguish anything about source or destination IPs either, I don't know where you've inferred that from.

Comment: what I said is accurate.  You cannot tell if both textboxes have the same number.  You may be correct there is an infinite loop, but the code can have more than one issue.

Comment: @jdweng sorry, but no. True - you can't prove the textboxes have the same number or not. You also don't know what's going on inside DroneClient, whether it's making any sort of connection or not. Therefore you can't say there's a networking issue or not. The error message reported by the OP is _clearly_ caused by the infinite instantiation of classes, which in any case will happen before any of the calls to DroneClient actually run. Therefore your statement "The root cause of you issue is an exception is occurring and has nothing to do with the instance of the class" is entirely inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I now understand the problem correctly, I think you need to supply your Arena class with the specific instances of Master that you want to use. At the moment you're creating brand new instances of Master and Arena in each of those classes respectively, which is causing the infinite loop (Master creates and Arena, which creates a Master, which creates and Arena, etc. etc. forever).

I think this may solve the problem:

Class 1 Inicio:

```
Master master = new Master(ip1.Text);
Master slave = new Master(ip2.Text);
Arena arena = new Arena(master, slave); //here we pass specific instances of Master to the Arena class for later use.
arena.Show();
```

Class 2 Master:

```
class Master
{
  public Master(string ip)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    _droneClient = new DroneClient("192.168.1." + ip);
    ip_drone = "192.168.1." + ip; 
    Point p2 = arena.posicao_desej();
    posicao_desejada = p2;
}

  public string ip_dron()
  {
     return ip_drone;
  }
}
```

Class 3 Arena:

```
class Arena
{
  private Master master;
  private Master slave;

  public Arena(Master master, Master slave) //hint: maybe Master is not such a good name for the class...but that's another story
  {
   //here we assign the instances passed in to our internal variables, so we can reference them within the Arena class itself.
    this.master = master;
    this.slave = slave;
  }
  //and then for example (this may not be what you really want to do):
  public string Show()
  {
    string masterIP = this.master.ip_dron();
    string slaveIP = this.slave.ip_dron();
    return "master IP: " + masterIP + ", Slave IP: " + slaveIP;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. -- Sorry for not being able to look at this earlier @TiagoSilva, but I'm glad you got your problem solved.

Comment: hello again, Adyson. Your example worked like wonders but now I need to pass Arena functions to Master. My problem is that if I try to pass arena instance to master and slave it says arena = null because arena is the third instance created.

Comment: I wanted something like: Master master = new Master(ip1.Text,arena);

Comment: @TiagoSilva Depending what you're trying to achieve, think whether you can do it in reverse and still make sense. Arena holds 2 instances of Master. Are they the ones that need information from Arena? Maybe Arena could give information at the right time, instead of being asked? Or maybe Master could fire an event which Arena could handle, and then provide the necessary info. There are many possible designs, but my instinct tells me that if you have two classes both needing to call each other (and it's not clear which instances this should apply to) then perhaps a logical rethink is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's some lack of code in your question, but to me it looks like this:

In every new `Master` class you initialize a new `Arena` instance:

```
Arena arena = new Arena();
```

then, in every new `Arena` class you initialize a new `Master` class:

```
Master master = new Master("");
```

So you seem to be initializing an infinite amount of `Arena` and `Master` classes. For every new `Arena` there'll be a new `Master`, and for every new `Master` there'll be a new `Arena.`

---

If you want to use the methods from the `Arena` and `Master` classes without having to create an instance all the time, you should declare them as `public static`. This makes them accessible without having to declare a class instance.

For example:

```
public class Arena
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something...
    }
}

public class Master
{
    public static void AnotherStaticMethod()
    {
        //Do something here too...
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to access the methods by calling either `Arena.DoSomething()` or `Master.AnotherStaticMethod()`.

Comment: The code is pretty simple. There's a WindowsForm called Inicio and when I click a button it opens 2 instances of Master (with different ips) and opens only one instance of Arena. I dont want to create new instances of Master or Arena. I just want to use the functions from Arena in Master class and vice-versa.

Comment: @TiagoSilva : I just updated my answer with how you can access methods without creating an instance of the parent class.

Comment: I had static instances before. People told me to change it. I will edit my question with the problem I had with static.

Comment: @TiagoSilva : I will in about an hour. I am a little busy right now.

Comment: The problem is that I cant use static most of the times because the values on those instances will return different values for each drone.